# Proof of Continuity of $f(x) = x^2 + x - 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Am supposed to show proof that $f(x) = x^2 + x - 1$ is continuous for all real numbers a.
Doing the general Delta-Epsilon proof, I have and understand how to prove $x^2$ alone.  In particular I am having trouble finding a proper $δ$ in terms of $ε$.

$|f(x) - f(a)| = |(x^2+x-1)-(a^2+a-1)| = |(x^2+x)-(a^2+a)| = |(x^2-a^2)+(x-a)|$

From here, I can say $|(x^2-a^2)+(x-a)|\leq |x^2-a^2|+|x-a|$ by Triangle Inequality, so then letting $δ < 1$ (as the proof of $x^2$ alone goes), I get $x < a+1$, so then $|x^2-a^2+x-a| < |2a+1+x-a|\leq |2a+1|+|x-a|$ again by Triangle Inequality.  $|2a+1|+|x-a|$ can be $<δ$ if I let $δ$ be the $min(1,-|2a+1|+ε)$, then $δ$ is not necessarily positive.

I know you can also say that $|(x^2-a^2)+(x-a)| = |x-a||x+a|+|x-a|$, but I have not been able to think of a $δ$ such that $|x-a||x+a|+|x-a|<ε$.

I believe my troubles are coming from not knowing how to properly arrange an equivalent form of $|f(x) - f(a)|$, but after spending a couple of hours at it, I haven't made any progress.  Could anyone advise?

EDIT: Thank you everyone for giving me the summation of continuous functions route, but we have not yet proven that, and cannot use it.  I realize this is a quick and easy proof, but the point of the exercise was to not use it, I should have specified it.

Comment: Mostly one proves that $x^2$ and $x-1$ is continuous and since a finite sum of continuous function is continous you get the desired result.

Comment: Unable to use the finite sum rule, haven't proven that sums of continuous functions are continuous, but if we could, that would definitely work.

Comment: You *could* just say that $x^2+x-1=(x+\frac{1}2)^2-\frac{5}4$ and reuse your proof that $x^2$ is continuous.

Comment: That a sum of two functions is continous can be directly shown by using that the limit of two convergent sequences is equal to the sum of their limits. You can use the "sequence definition" of continuinity.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, we want to factor out the $|x - a|$, then use the fact that $\delta < 1$ in order to bound what's left over.

---

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min(1, \tfrac{\epsilon}{1 + |2a + 1|}) > 0$. Then if $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
|(x^2 + x - 1) - (a^2 + a - 1)|
&= |(x^2 - a^2) + (x - a)| \\
&= |(x - a)(x + a) + (x - a)(1)| \\
&= |x - a||x + a + 1| \\
&= |x - a||(x  - a) + (2a + 1)| \\
&\leq |x - a|(|x - a| + |2a + 1|) &\text{by the triangle inequality}\\
&< |x - a|(1 + |2a + 1|) &\text{since } |x - a| < \delta \leq 1 \\
&< \tfrac{\epsilon}{1 + |2a + 1|}(1 + |2a + 1|) &\text{since } |x - a| < \delta \leq \tfrac{\epsilon}{1 + |2a + 1|} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The sum of continuous functions is continuous.  This is not too difficult to prove.  Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions.  Then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f+g)(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) + \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x) = f(x_0) + g(x_0) = (f+g)(x_0)$$
Above, I used the theorem that limits split across a sum.

Now we can separately prove $x^2$ is continuous, prove $x$ is continuous, and prove $-1$ is continuous.  Then use the fact that the sum of continuous functions is continuous, and you're done.

Comment: That's not a rigorous proof, it's more or less a sketch of the actual proof.